# Properties of homomorphisms of the additive group of rationals

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, rational-numbers

Let $f : (\mathbb{Q},+) \longrightarrow (\mathbb{Q},+)$ be a non-zero homomorphism.

Can we conclude that $f$ is bijective (or, if  that   fails, that $f$ is injective or surjective)?

#### Context

The additive group of integers has non-surjective nonzero endomorphisms, such as $n\mapsto 2n$. However, the same formula gives a bijective endomorphism when applied to rationals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose $\,f\,$ is such a homomorphism and try to work out how knowing $\,f(1)\,$ can help you out, say:
$$\forall\,n\in\Bbb Z\,\,,\,\,f(n)=f(n\cdot 1)=nf(1)$$
$$f(1)=f\left(\frac{n}{n}\right)=nf\left(\frac{1}{n}\right).....etc.$$

So you know the values of $\,f\,$ on the integers and then on the rationals of the form $\,1/n\,$ and thus...