# Let $f : (\Bbb Q,+) \to (\Bbb Q,+)$ be a non-zero homomorphism. Pick out the true statements

Tags: abstract-algebra

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [homomorphism. Pick out the true statements](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/179556/homomorphism-pick-out-the-true-statements)

[NBHM-2006-PhD Screening Test-Algebra]

> Let $f : (\Bbb Q,+) \to (\Bbb Q,+)$ be a non-zero homomorphism. Pick
>   out the true statements:
>
> a. $f$ is always one-one.
>
> b. $f$ is always onto.
>
> c. $f$ is always a bijection.
>
> d. $f$ need be neither one-one nor onto.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: hint: think about how $f(1)$ affects what the homomorphism could be.

Comment: To elaborate a bit on David Wheeler's hint: Assume that you have decided what $f(1)$ would be. What choices do you have for $f(2)$, $f(1/2)$, $f(3)$, $f(1/3)$, $f(2/3)$, $f(3/2),\ldots$?

Answer (score 6):

Let $p=f(1)$.

1. Prove that $f(2)=2p$; you’ll use the fact that $f$ is a homomorphism.
2. Prove by induction that $f(n)=np$ for every non-negative integer $n$.
3. Use the result of (2) and the fact that $f$ is a homomorphism to prove that $f(n)=np$ for every negative integer $n$ as well.
4. Use (2) to prove that if $n$ is a positive integer, then $f\left(\frac1n\right)=\frac{p}n$.
5. Prove that for any $q\in\Bbb Q$, $f(q)=qp$; you’ll find it useful to write $q$ in the form $\frac{m}n$ for integers $m$ and $n$.
6. Conclude that if $f$ is non-zero, then $f$ is a bijection.

Comment: In 4. do you mean $f(\frac{1}{n}) = \frac{p}{n}$?

Comment: @Arthur: I sure do. (I changed an earlier version and typoed it in the process.)

Comment: Typos aside, what all these steps do is 1. show that any homomorphism is multiplication by some number, and 2. show that multiplication (by a non-zero number) is a bijection in $\Bbb Q$

Comment: @Arthur: Absolutely; in my notation, by $p$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(1) = a$.
Then $f(n) = na$ for every integer $n$.
Let $n, m \in \mathbb{Z}$, $m > 0$.
Then $mf(n/m) = f(n) = na$.
Hence $f(n/m) = (n/m)a$.
Hence $f$ is bijective, since $a \neq 0$(otherwise $f$ must be $0$).

So the answer is $a, b, c$.