# Let $f:(\mathbb F,+)\to (\mathbb F,+)$ be a non-zero homomorphism. Then which is true?

Tags: group-theory, continuous-homomorphisms

Its  (may be) asking about the generalization of [this question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197907/let-f-bbb-q-to-bbb-q-be-a-non-zero-homomorphism-pick-out-the-tru)

Let $f : (\Bbb F,+) \to (\Bbb F,+)$ be a non-zero homomorphism. Pick out the true statements:

a. $f$ is always one-one.

b. $f$ is always onto.

c. $f$ is always a bijection.

d. $f$ need be neither one-one nor onto.

That is, what can you say about if the $\mathbb Q$ is replaced by a Field $\mathbb F$? We can discuss the both finite and infinite field? What about the continuity?

Comment: Which what is true?

Comment: see the link http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/197907/let-f-bbb-q-to-bbb-q-be-a-non-zero-homomorphism-pick-out-the-tru

Comment: So, you are repeating that question, or are you asking the new question about other fields only? Because the title is still about $\mathbb Q$. It is always preferable for questions to be self-contained, so we don't have to follow links to understand your question.

Comment: yes.. I need a generalization.. if it confuses, i will edit the title..

Comment: First point: Continuity doesn't make sense when referring to fields in general.

Comment: yes.. you are right.. kindly discuss about the continuity for $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$ with usual norm.@ThomasAndrews

Comment: What is the question about continuity? Is the question about what happens if we restrict the question to continuous homomorphisms, or is the question about whether all homomorphisms will be continuous?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, any field is a vector space over $\mathbb F_p$ or $\mathbb Q$. So you can write the basis of $\mathbb F$ over the appropriate field and send the elements of that basis to *any* values in $\mathbb F$ with at least one value is non-zero.

(a,b,c) Are all only true if $\mathbb F\cong\mathbb F_p,$ for some prime $p$, or $\mathbb F\cong\mathbb Q$.

(d) Is true for all other fields.

Not sure what is meant about continuity, but most homomorphisms $(\mathbb R,+)\to(\mathbb R,+)$ are not continuous, and same for $\mathbb C$.

Comment: So, you mean that $f$ can not be one-one if $\mathbb F\mathbb R$. Right? then what about the identity map?@Thomasandrews

Comment: It is possible for $f$ to not be one-to-one, not that all $f$ are not $1-1$. "$f$ need be neither one-one nor onto" is an awkward English language phrase, but it means "it is possible for $f$ to not be ...." The option would be ludicrous otherwise, as your identity map example would indicate.

Comment: oh.. got it...thank you so much..

Comment: amazing know.. If we define just a homomorphism from  a finite field to same field or $\mathbb Q\to \mathbb Q$ that will be and automorphism...

Comment: Not all finite fields, only the ones with prime elements. $\mathbb F_4$ does not work. Basically, we need there to be no subfields.

Comment: yes.. thankyou for the observe.. I thinked wrong..